# Is there a solution Wordpress 5.8 incompatibility with widgets?

Tags: wordpress

I made an update from Wordpress 5.5 to 5.8 but experiencing errors highlighted below

`The "search" block was affected by errors and may not function properly. Check the developer tools for more details`

What is the best move of going about it without downgrading to the previous version?

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and your attempts to resolve the problem. Maybe this fits better on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: I just wanted to customize the site so I just used the GUI where I click the appearance from the wp-admin then click on the widgets. Thats where the error begins